# "joe" on Debian 11

Tags: debian, joe

I have a fresh cloud server with Debian 11 and am trying to install my favorite litte editor `joe`, but cannot find it:

```
root@serv:~# apt-cache search joe
root@serv:~# apt install joe
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package joe
root@serv:~# uname -a
Linux serv 5.10.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.46-4 (2021-08-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I remember doing it on some other machine (maybe Debian 10?) and it worked.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given

> I have a fresh cloud server with Debian 11

I suspect you need to run `apt update`.

[`joe` is present in Debian 11](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/joe).

Comment: Well that was embarrising for me. :) Thanks!